# Adding and removing multiple nodes efficiently, without any lag

Tags: swift, scenekit

In my game, at specific intervals, a function is called that adds multiple nodes to the scene (between 2 and 6 nodes). These individual nodes are all the same - they consist of the same blender model, same SCNCone, same spotlight and same physics bodies - (The blender model is low-poly, nothing extreme).

When it's time to call the next interval of nodes, the nodes that were called previously are removed (including their actions). This process repeats until the player has died. Now when the nodes are removed and new ones are added, it creates noticeable lag for roughly a second, and doesn't appear smooth.

I'm wondering whether there is a more efficient way to add and remove these nodes that could possibly eliminate lag? Since these nodes are all visibly the same, would cloning a node multiple times be better than re-creating the same node over and over within a for loop?

Any advice on efficiency or better practises would be greatly appreciated too.

Thanks!

**Edit:** Just a thought, should I have a node at every required position, and basically un-hide and give them actions when needed, and once they've done their job, fade out, put back at initial position, remove actions and hide?

This would mean I would need about 20 nodes in the scene at all times, but at least there would be no need to add any more, or remove any.

Answer (score 2):

Start by turning ON statistics.

```
scnView.showStatistics = YES;
```

Click on the + at the bottom left of the screen to the stats screen.

What could be causing the lag?  Quick things to check are:

```
1. Is the geometry too complex?  
2. Are the textures too large?
3. Are there too many draw calls?
```

Cloning is better.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think your idea at the end will avoid the lag. If the nodes being added are the same as the nodes being removed it will be more efficient just to hide and reset them.

If you are creating the nodes each time it is likely that is causing the lag, and you could even remove and add them from the scene but instead of creating them when needed store them in an array ready to be reused.